# Avoid page scrolling when md-menu is open in IOS

Tags: angularjs, node.js

md-menu allows scrolling behind the menu on iOS.I have stucked in this issue.Can anybody know how to avoid scrolling??

Answer (score 0):

I had to find the answer to my question.Actually, i can't avoid scrolling but I have closed the md-menu in outer page scrolling.

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', hideMdMenu, false);

    /**
     * Method close md-menu when scrolling the page in IOS.
     * 
     * @author Ideas2IT Technologies
     */
    function hideMdMenu() {
        var standalone = window.navigator.standalone,

        userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
        safari = /safari/.test( userAgent ),
        ios = /iphone|ipod|ipad/.test( userAgent );

        if( ios ) {
            mdmenu.close();
        } 
    }
```

That works in IOS